# Converting json object from redis and extract List from it

Tags: java

I have this json  value in redis for the key temp_se  : `{ \"seq\": \"[12,23] \"} .`
Now in one line i want to get the sequence part `([12,23])` as a list  .

Something like using it as below :

```
 String ob =  new ObjectMapper().readValue(tmpl.getTemplateSequenceinString(tem_se), 
                                              HashMap.class).get("seq");
```

then convert ob to list .

Can i do it in a more optimized way.